# Saving Form-data in order while having multiple Input-elements with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to create a form to create new Pages. I added buttons to dynamically create different Inputs like a h1-heading, a p-Paragraph and a code-Field. All h1-inputs get the same name e.g.:"e-h1[]". Now I want to save all Form-data in the order of the created input-elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="button-bar">
  <button id="e-h1" name="e-h1" onclick="CreateNewHeadingOne()">Überschrift H</button>
  <button id="e-p" name="e-p" onclick="CreateNewParapgraph()">Paragraph P</button>
  <button id="e-code" name="e-code" onclick="CreateNewCodeArea()">Codebereich C</button>
</div>
<form id="editor" method="post">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function CreateNewHeadingOne() {
  var DOMHeadingOne = document.createElement("input");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("name", "e-h1[]");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("type", "text");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("placeholder", "Überschrift");
  DOMHeadingOne.classList.add("e-h1");
document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMHeadingOne);
}

function CreateNewParapgraph(){
  var DOMParagraph = document.createElement("textarea");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("name", "e-p[]");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("rows", "7");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("placeholder", "Dies ist ein Paragraph-Feld. Bitte für jeden Paragraph ein eigenes Feld erstellen.");
  DOMParagraph.classList.add("e-p");
  document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMParagraph);
}

function CreateNewCodeArea(){
  var DOMCodeArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("name", "e-code[]");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("rows", "12");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Code-Bereich");
  DOMCodeArea.classList.add("e-code");
  document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMCodeArea);
}
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['createPage'])) {
    $title = $_POST['e-title'];
    $category = $_POST['e-category'];
    $arrayHeading = $_POST['e-h1'];
    $arrayParagraph = $_POST['e-p'];
    $arrayCode = $_POST['e-code'];

    foreach ($arrayHeading as $head){
        $heading = "<h1>".$head."</h1>";
    }
    foreach ($arrayParagraph as $par){
        $paragraph = "<p>".$par."</p>";
    }
    foreach ($arrayCode as $cod){
        $code = "<pre class='code'><code>".$cod."</code></pre>";
    }

    $result = $heading.$paragraph.$code;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to loop through the elements, but obviously I don't get the right order. Any ideas?

EXAMPLE:

```
<form id="editor" method="post">
  <input name="e-h1[]" type="text" class="e-h1"/>
  <textarea name="e-p[]" rows="7" class="e-p"></textarea>
  <textarea name="e-p[]" rows="7" class="e-p"></textarea>
  <textarea name="e-code[]" rows="12" class="e-code"></textarea>
  <textarea name="e-p[]" rows="7" class="e-p"></textarea>
  <textarea name="e-code[]" rows="12" class="e-code"></textarea>
</form>
```

So I want to keep the order in which the elements have been created. In this case : H1 -> P -> P -> Code -> P -> Code

EDIT:

I used another dimension of the array to get the position through the index. So I changed the name of the input elements like this `DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("name", "inputs[][e-h1]");` and looped two times to get the positions.

JS:

```
function CreateNewHeadingOne() {
  var DOMHeadingOne = document.createElement("input");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("name", "inputs[][e-h1]");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("type", "text");
  DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("placeholder", "Überschrift");
  DOMHeadingOne.classList.add("e-h1");
  document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMHeadingOne);
}

function CreateNewParapgraph(){
  var DOMParagraph = document.createElement("textarea");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("name", "inputs[][e-p]");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("rows", "7");
  DOMParagraph.setAttribute("placeholder", "Dies ist ein Paragraph-Feld. Bitte für jeden Paragraph ein eigenes Feld erstellen.");
  DOMParagraph.classList.add("e-p");
  document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMParagraph);
}

function CreateNewCodeArea(){
  var DOMCodeArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("name", "inputs[][e-code]");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("rows", "12");
  DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Code-Bereich");
  DOMCodeArea.classList.add("e-code");
  document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMCodeArea);
}
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['createPage'])) {
    $arrayInputs = $_POST['inputs'];
    $result = "";
    foreach($arrayInputs as $position){
        foreach($position as $index => $value){
            switch($index){
                case "e-h1":
                    $result .= "<h1>".$value."</h1>";
                    break;
                case "e-p":
                    $result .= "<p>".$value."</p>";
                    break;
                case "e-code":
                    $result .= "<pre class='code'><code>".$value."</code></pre>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: The posted parameters should appear in the same order as the controls have in the document, however you overrule this by grouping them into arrays. It would be easiest if you gave each control a unique name, like `e-code1`,  `e-code2`,  `e-code3`, etc, and them process them in the order they appear in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0):

why not create a const nameAppend = 0 , which you can increment at the end of each function and just concat this nameAppend at the input name.
That way you will have all the inputs/paragraphs or whatever they are, with names like :

```
// i don't know if those functions are inside of a class or not so you will need to chose yourself how you define those variables.
const headingConcat = 0;
const paragraphConcat = 0;
const codeAreaConcat = 0;

function CreateNewHeadingOne() {
    var DOMHeadingOne = document.createElement("input");
    DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("name", "e-h" + headingConcat);
    DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("type", "text");
    DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("placeholder", "Überschrift");
    DOMHeadingOne.classList.add("e-h1");
    document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMHeadingOne);
    headingConcat ++;
}

function CreateNewParapgraph(){
    var DOMParagraph = document.createElement("textarea");
    DOMParagraph.setAttribute("name", "e-p" + paragraphConcat);
    DOMParagraph.setAttribute("rows", "7");
    DOMParagraph.setAttribute("placeholder", "Dies ist ein Paragraph-Feld. Bitte für jeden Paragraph ein eigenes Feld erstellen.");
    DOMParagraph.classList.add("e-p");
    document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMParagraph);
paragraphConcat ++;
}

function CreateNewCodeArea(){
    var DOMCodeArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("name", "e-code" + codeAreaConcat);
    DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("rows", "12");
    DOMCodeArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Code-Bereich");
    DOMCodeArea.classList.add("e-code");
    document.getElementById("editor").appendChild(DOMCodeArea);
codeAreaConcat ++;
```

`}`

the problem here appears when you get to PHP and you search for each element in the POST, but you could search in a foreach loop after the pattern that you already set like  'e-h' or 'e-p'.
for eaxample :

```
$data = $_POST;
$paragraphData = [];
$headingData = [];
$codeAreaData = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
       if(substr('e-p',$key) { // search with kind of input it is
            $paragraphData[$key] = $value;
        } 
       if(substr('e-h',$key) { // search with kind of input it is
            $headingData[$key] = $value;
        } 
       if(substr('e-code',$key) { // search with kind of input it is
            $codeAreaData[$key] = $value;
        } 
    }
```

In the end you will have 3 array variables with all your input data... Hopefully that was relevant to your question .

Comment: I understand your approach and it is relevant indeed. I managed to get it working with another approach. I used two Arrays for the inputs `DOMHeadingOne.setAttribute("name", "inputs[][e-h1]");` in which the first Index resembles the position and the second Index resembles the "type of input". In the PHP I looped the first arraydimension and in this loop i loop to get the inputtype. See edited Question for further details.

Comment: i suppose it depends on how fast you want your code to be, not so sure which approach is better since this is the only idea i had on the spot. Glad you got your answer. Good luck.

Comment: I thank you very much, I'll try to test out your solution, too.